# How to add /en/routerLink to url in angular

Tags: angular

I made my page in English with ngx translate core, but when the company translates the page to English, they want /en/ in the url, how do I do that?

Comment: You could define the route like `route: /:lang/pageName` and use the `lang` parameter to  setup the language of your translation service/pipe/logic. This way you'll have just one route forEach language you want.

Comment: @JacopoSciampi where do i do what you say i am a newbie

Comment: your root routerModule will have ":lang", and all other pages and modules will be child of that.

Answer (score 1):

First, I suggest you to have a look at the [Tour of Heroes](https://angular.io/tutorial/tour-of-heroes)

Second, this is a [live example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-s3fnj9?file=src%2Ftest.component.ts)

Anyway, the approach I used is very simple (and of course *must* be adapted, improved and better handlded. It's just for a demonstration purpose).

I've defined the route for the *component* as following:

```
{
    path: 'site/:lang/foo',
    component: TestComponent,
},
```

Then I've added a generic function that loads the component by its route passing a dynamic language:

```
this._router.navigate([`site/${lang}/foo`]);
```

Finally, in the component, I just print out the data:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-test-component',
  template: `
  <div>Page is in {{lang}}</div>
  <div>Full URL: {{url}}</div>
  `,
  styles: [``],
  standalone: true,
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
  public lang!: string;
  public url!: string;

  constructor(private _ar: ActivatedRoute) {}

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.lang = this._ar.snapshot.params?.lang === 'en' ? 'English' : 'Spanish';
    this.url = window.location.href;
  }
}
```

The result in the window is:

> Page is in English

> Full URL: https://stackblitz-starters-s3fnj9.stackblitz.io/#/site/en/foo

*Note the `en` in the url*

By clicking the `es` button, you'll see the component and the url changing according to your request.